# What algorithm do the NoHalo and LoHalo resize methods use in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, image-quality, research

The GIMP resize tool used to have only None, Linear, Cubic/Bicubic, and Lanczos, which are reasonably well documented algorithms that one can do research on, if one is so inclined.

I can't find any information about resizing algorithms under the names "**NoHalo**" or "**LoHalo**." Any idea what algorithms these methods use?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**NoHalo** and **LoHalo** are the new **[GEGL](http://www.gegl.org/)** [samplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling), developed by [Nicolas Robidoux](https://scholar.google.ca/citations?user=Rd8f9jYAAAAJ&hl=en) to reduce the blur in the resampled images.

**NoHalo level 1** consists of one diagonal straightening subdivision followed by bilinear interpolation, as described in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1557626.1557657):

> *Like many edge-enhancing methods, Nohalo has two main stages: first,*
> *nonlinear interpolation is used to create a double-density version of*
> *the original image; this doubledensity image is then resampled with*
> *bilinear interpolation. Nohalo is especially suited for GPU computing*
> *because the nonlinear slopes can be computed once and stored in a low*
> *bit-depth texture without rounding error, because the final bilinear*
> *stage can be performed in hardware, and because monotonicity allows*
> *full use of the texture’s dynamic range.*

In the paper you can find also a comparison with [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) method.

**LoHalo** is described as a sigmoidized EWA (Elliptical Weighted Averaging) with the Robidoux bicubic for upsampling, blended with non-sigmoidized EWA Robidoux for downsampling.

The author introduced [on GimpUsers](https://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-developer/11910-new-gegl-samplers-what-they-are-and-where-they-are-going) the new samplers, and [crowfounded](https://freedomsponsors.org/issue/78/add-other-samplers-that-properly-reduce-downsample-and-warp-images) the development of the algorithms.

You can find [here](https://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/whats-new-in-gimp-2-10) a brief description of this family of samplers:

- LoHalo method: when you downscale an image that's less than a half of the original size
- NoHalo method when you do not reduce the size much (rotate, shear or something)
- LoBlur method (yet to come) focuses on output sharpness. It is based on standard tensor Lanczos 3 for upsampling, blended with EWA Lanczos Radius 3 for downsampling.
- LoJaggy (yet to come) is a special method and aimed at reducing jaggyness. This method is similar to [EWA LanczosSharp](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/).

These samplers can be emulated using [ImageMagick resampling filers](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/), developed by Nicolas Robidoux himself.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Thanks!